# MISRA 13.5 question about non-compilant example

Tags: c, misra

Trying to understand a non-compliant example of Rule 13.5.

MISRA-2012 Rule 13.5 states "The right hand operand of a logical && or || operator shall not contain persistent side eﬀects"  With the rationale being "... the side effects may or may not occure which may be contrary to programmer expectations."
I understand and totally agree with this.  However their final example of non-compliant code is:

```
/* Non-compliant if fp points to a function with persistent side effects */ 

( fp != NULL ) && ( *fp ) ( 0 );
```

This construct seems perfectly safe in that the condition and the decision to call the function are directly tied, where the intent is to not dereference a NULL pointer.  I understand an if statement would be clearer but would be interested if anyone has further insight.

Comment: Well, the comment is explaining it and it looks like the standard is simply makes no exceptions. I highly dislike MISRA for it being too strict up to a point making a completely different language out of C.

Comment: MISRA is from the K&R age where compilers where stupid and did not provide much diagnostics.  It contains a lot of rules which do not make much sense nowadays and which will make the program unsafe.  E.g. MISRA requires lot of explicit casts which disables type safety completely.  Your rule is a another example. ... Best thing in MISRA is that you can define exemptions.

Comment: @ensc, _"MISRA is from the K&R age"_ Hmm, really?

Comment: What I read is that the rule says that it is not allowed if you call a function that e.g. modifies a global variable (a "persistent side efect" of the function). The rule does not forbid the construction.

Comment: @ensc, 2012 is hardly "the K&R age", and MISRA *started* in the early 90s, after the original C standard was published.  It could hardly have been written without the standard, as there was significant variation among pre-standard compilers on various relevant matters.

Comment: @ensc the C standard does not require a compiler to be intelligent, only to compile correct code. There is no guarantee that a cross-compiler supplied with a MCU has the intelligence you might expect. I think the point of MISRA is that code is often destined for an operating environment where diagnostics are difficult and the code has to be 100% reliable and work as intended.

Comment: @JoeyMallone nearly... it is from 1996.  Ok; there was C89/90, but K&R coding style and compilers still alive.

Comment: @WeatherVane exactly; MISRA was from a time where compilers were shipped in 5.25" discs and provided zero diagnostics.  Haiving rules to catch common programming errors was useful at this time.  But today, it makes more harm than use.

Comment: This specific example was from MISRA-2012, also I work primarially in Embedded and while I don't always agree with MISRA I like my development tools to be a pedantic as possible to keep me honest.

Comment: @ensc please point me to the modern standard that obliges compilers to catch common programming errors, or obliges a certain warning level for code destinated for a sensitive application, and what those warning levels should include. Your casual approach seems to be "heck, trust the compiler, I know what I am doing" which is perhpas why MISRA was needed in the first place.

Comment: There is no reason not to DEVIATE the rule... this requires you to justify why the violation can be accepted.  MISRA Compliance explains the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This construct seems perfectly safe in that the condition and the decision to call the function are directly tied, where the intent is to not dereference a NULL pointer. I understand an if statement would be clearer but would be interested if anyone has further insight.

MISRA attempts to define rules that can be interpreted without having to guess the programmer's intent.  So yes, the construct you present is fine if it is intentional to avoid the function call in the event that the pointer is NULL, but a machine performing MISRA analysis of that code does not necessarily recognize that likelihood.  The rule is primarily aimed at conditional statements where the two operands of `&&` or `||` are not directly related.  Rejecting the case you describe is collateral damage.

Of course, you can replace your case with

```
if (fp != NULL) {
    (*fp)(0);
}
```

.  Personally, I find the `if` statement clearer than the original expression statement.  That's not such a clear call when an expression such as your original one appears in the condition of an `if`, `while`, or `for` statement, but all of those can be restructured to comply with MISRA, too.

Comment: This is what I was thinking also, and I would also generally use the "if" statement.  It just struck me as an odd example.  The particular form is so common in things like BASH scripts and some other languagues.

Answer (score 0):

Rule 13.5 is a *Required* Rule, and seeks to prevent situations where a user might assume the the right hand side is executed, but for the sort-circuit evaluation.

In situations like the example cited, it is (probably) OK - in fact, this is quite a common idiom.

There are two options...

1. Restructure the code, as suggested by @John Bollinger
2. Deviate the Rule - this requires you to justify why the Rule may be safely violated, which in the case cited, should be straight-forward

*See profile for affilation*